# Database CURRENT_TIMESTAMP comparison

Tags: php, sql

Can anyone give me a solution  how can i make an sql request to compare date in my database

```
SELECT * FROM my table WHERE date between YY.MM.DD HH.MM.SS AND YY.MM.DD HH.MM.SS
```

Thanks

Comment: There are a lot of examples [HERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Comment: It depends of your brand of SQL.  MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc, etc.  And it depends on how your're querying, ADO.NET, JDO, etc, etc.

Comment: You forgot the father of them all: Sybase :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't state your DBMS so this is the ANSI version:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE date between timestamp '2012-05-01 18:00:00' AND timestamp '2012-05-19 23:00:00'
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE date between timestamp '2012-05-01 18:00:00' AND current_timestamp
```